# Plotly legend title

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to be able to add a title to the legend, in the following code. However, looking at the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/legend/#legend-names), I don't think there is a method for this.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

py.iplot(fig, filename='default-legend')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

For not defining the legend but having the annotation positioned property please use the below code.

```
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=1.12,
            y=1.05,
            align="right",
            valign="top",
            text='Legend Title',
            showarrow=False,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            xanchor="center",
            yanchor="top"
        )
    ]
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout = layout)

py_offline.iplot(fig)
```

**Notes:**

1. You need to define `x` and `y` position for annotations using this method, for varying legends.
2. You can use html inside the `text` attribute(E.g: `text='Legend Title<br>kinda lengthy',`)

**Previous Attempt:**

Another approach would to create the legend and use annotations to add the title to the legend. Provided you do not use the graph in editable mode. So in the below example, the legend is set to x=0 and y=1, since I want my legend title to be above my actual legend, I set the annotation location as x = 0, y= 1.5. x-ref and y-ref needs to be set to paper. This will give a nice annotation like
[image: plotly legend title]

Code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    legend=dict(
        x=0,
        y=1,
        traceorder='normal',
        font=dict(
            family='sans-serif',
            size=12,
            color='#000'
        ),
        bgcolor='#E2E2E2',
        bordercolor='#FFFFFF',
        borderwidth=2
    ),
    annotations=[
        dict(
            x=0,
            y=1.05,
            xref='paper',
            yref='paper',
            text='Legend Title',
            showarrow=False
        )
    ]
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout = layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: @blueprince13 can this question be closed?

Comment: Could you please suggest how this could be done without specifically setting the legend? I want the legend to appear in the same place that it would normally.

Comment: @blueprince13 If the other solution doesn't satisfy your problem, please check my updated answer!

Answer (score 13):

I've done this before by making a data-less trace

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

dummy_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[None], y=[None],
    name='<b>Legend Heading</b>',
    # set opacity = 0
    line={'color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}
)

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [dummy_trace, trace0, trace1]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: That's genious!

Answer (score 8):

As of plotly v4.5, legend titles have been added.
You can add a title for a legend by
`fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Legend title')`

Find an example in the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#legend-titles).

Answer (score 3):

Just a slight addition of property `name` to the already proposed solution,

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace0 = go.Scatter(
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
name="Data1")

data = [trace0]
layout = go.Layout(
legend=dict(
    x=0,
    y=1,
    traceorder='normal',
    font=dict(
        family='sans-serif',
        size=12,
        color='#000'
    ),
    bgcolor='#E2E2E1',
    bordercolor='#FFFFFF',
    borderwidth=2
),
annotations=[
    dict(
        x=0,
        y=1.05,
        xref='paper',
        yref='paper',
        text='Legend Title',
        showarrow=False
    )
])
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout = layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

The `name` property helps in adding custom names to the legends defined.

Answer (score 3):

Currently with the last version of plotly `5.5.0`, all you need:

```
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

fig.update_layout(legend={"title":"Points"})  #<--- add only this line

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to plotly with jupyter through wrapper cufflinks.

install these dependencies:

```
!pip install pandas cufflinks plotly
```

create data frame from your data.

```
import pandas as pd
```

load data

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

make second y list to y1

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

create dataframe from your data list

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "y1": y1}).set_index("x")
```

load cufflinks and its configuration

```
import cufflinks as cf
cf.set_config_file(offline=True)
```

plot dataframe

```
data.iplot()
```

You will x on axis, y, y1 on y axis. You can show and hide line clicking on legend from right side.

References:

- https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/

Answer (score 0):

Another (now probably moot) option for *discrete* data is using one of a dataframe's column headers as the legend title. Below an example for a choropleth map consisting of three (Geo)DataFrames.

```
df1['Legend'] = 'Label1'
df2['Legend'] = 'Label2'
df3['Legend'] = 'Label3'
merged = df1.append(df2)
merged = df2.append(df3)

fig = px.choropleth(merged, geojson=merged.geometry, locations=merged.index, color=merged['Legend'], color_discrete_map={
    'Label1':'red',
    'Label2':'lightgrey',
    'Label3':'lightblue'})
```

And here an example using a mapbox choropleth
[image: improvised choropleth map legend using column name]