# Basic code from plotly's own website doesn't work. How do I handle a Layout property ceasing to exist?

Tags: python, plotly, legend-properties

I'm getting an error trying to set the legend title, which should be very basic. Eventually I tried the code on plotly's website, and even that didn't work.

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Figure, Scatter
fig = Figure()
fig.add_trace(Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,2,3,4,5], name='Increasing'))
fig.add_trace(Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[5,4,3,2,1], name='Decreasing'))
fig.update_layout(legend_title='<b> Trend </b>')
fig.show()
```

The error I'm getting is:

`Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'legend_title'

The computer I'm trying it on (in Jupyter Notebook) is running Python 3.6.5 and plotly 4.4.1. The code *does* work on a different computer running Python 3.7.1 and plotly 4.6.0. However, all of those versions seem relatively new. For reasons, I can't upgrade the Python or plotly versions of the computer that I can't get it to work on (which is the computer that I need to get it to work on). Is my plotly corrupted? I tried '!pip install plotly' but that didn't do anything. I then tried "!pip uninstall plotly' but that just locked up the cell at [*]. Is there another way to reinstall plotly? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555266/plotly-legend-title

Comment: @Mari I'd seen that answer, but it's a somewhat clunky workaround (creating an annotation at coordinates just above the legend), and I'd like to know why the basic code works on one computer but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend_title` was introduced in Plotly v4.5 so yes, you will need to upgrade: https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-5/34045

Comment: Thank you, @nicolaskruchten. I have to admit I'm surprised by the reason. I have no idea how I was supposed to find that link on my own, so thank you for saving me time.